# Mozilla -moz-border-radius and -moz-box-shadow is not recognized

Tags: css, mozilla

Mozilla tells me on the console that `-moz-border-radius` and `-moz-box-shadow` is not recognized. Why not recognized? I have Mozilla 14.0.1  on Linux!

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_13_for_developers#CSS, "Support for `-moz-border-radius*` and `-moz-box-shadow` has been removed. Authors should use unprefixed border-radius or box-shadow instead. See [bug 693510](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693510)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the latest version supports: `border-radius: 10px;`

You don't need `-moz-` it was necessary before firefox version 3.0

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Is now equivalent to -

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Ok. i have:    border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; I have to stay only border-radius or should I leave it like that?

Comment: Keep only border-radius and remove -moz- and -webkit- it's not needed anymore

Comment: Thanks to all! Last question, but if I do remain only border-radius older versions of browsers will display the same border radius?

Comment: No! If you wish to support older versions you need to use the first code with vendor specific CSS

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that is a Mozilla specific (i.e. Firefox) CSS selector. The relevant CSS3 selector would be:

```
border-radius:xxpx;
```

`-webkit-`... will only be recognized by WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari), `-moz-`... will only be recognized by Mozilla-based browsers (Firefox.)

Try this link

When can I use CSS3 Border-radius?
http://caniuse.com/border-radius